# Cannot alter settings of XmlWriter

Tags: c#, xml, xmlwriter

I am having some trouble with the XmlWriter class. I create and instantiate it using the XmlWriter.Create() method, but when I do it becomes a type XmlWellFormedWriter. I want to be able to write XML fragments to a file but when I try to do so I encounter an exception which tells me to set the Conformance Level to Auto or Fragment. I have tried to change the settings after instantiating the object:

```
XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(filepath);
writer.settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Auto;
```

But I encounter a exception saying that the Conformance Level is read-only and cannot be set.

I have also tried creating settings and having my XmlWriter inherhit them:

```
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Auto;
XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(filepath, settings);
```

But the created XmlWriter instance overrides my settings with its own, setting the Conformance level to Document. How can I fix this? I am using [this website](http://www.dotnetperls.com/xmlwriter) as a tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `XmlWriter` behaves like it should. `ConformanceLevel.Auto` specifies that the XML writer should determine the level of conformance checking based on the incoming data. This setting can be useful when you don't know whether the generated XML will be a well-formed XML document or a fragment. In your case its switching to `ConformanceLevel.Document`. The ConformanceLevel property can be used to check for specifc incoming data, `ConformanceLevel.Document` or `ConformanceLevel.Fragment`.

Comment: Alright, I set it to ConformanceLevel.Fragment in both of those examples and it still isn't working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When I declare writer using the Createmethod, the object that gets created is an XmlWellFormedWriter, not an XmlWriter. Also I cannot modify the settings.

Comment: The XmlWellFormedWriter class is an implementation of the XmlWriter abstract class. The Create method uses the XmlWriterSettings class to specify which features to implement in the XmlWriter object that is created. Just setup the XmlWriterSettings you need and then call the Create method. The create method retuns the right XmlWriter based on the given settings in the call.

Comment: When I do that it creates an XMlWellFormedWriter and overrides the settings I want with its own settings. EDIT: I'm an idiot, forgot to add the settings to the Create method. It works now.